# Two's Complement Addition Resulting In A Negative

Tags: binary, addition, twos-complement

I understand the concept of using two's complement to represent a negative value which can then be used in addition to find the resulting value.

ex.
`x = 15` and `y = 10`, in binary `x = 1111` and `y = 1010`
for calculating `x - y`, we represent `y` as a negative using twos complement which results `y = 0101 + 0001 = 0110` then carrying out the addition `x + (-y) = 1111 + 0110 = 0101` which translates to the expected result `5`.

All is well and fine until I try to use the same method to calculate `y - x` which ends up resulting in `1011` translating to `11`, not the expected result `-5`. Is there a way to properly calculate the addition of two binary numbers resulting in a negative value?

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way; `y - x` is equivalent to `-x + y`.  For that reason, we can first negate `x`, which is `15` (`1111` in binary), which becomes `0001` after negation.  We can then add that value to `y` (which is `10`, `1010` in binary), which results in `1011`.  Because this value is negative, we then flip the bits and add 1 to make it positive, and we get `0101`, which is `5` in base-10.  This means that our result was `-5`, which is correct.

I think you were correct everywhere except where you stated that it translates to `11`.